# Is it easy to add e-mail verification down the road with restful_authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

Working on a new app and using restful-authentication. I was trying to make it as simple as possible to start and then iterate, so I didn't generate with the activation email functionality, planning to add it later down the road. Is there an easy way to do this later on using the existing plugin?

Comment: thanks for the answers guys! I checked out clearance which looks like a great option too. Going to stick with restful for this first go around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just rerun the generator with option -include-validation. It will add extra code to your model user and session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting you should take a look at clearance by thoughtbot.  It's a great authentication plugin.